# EXTJS How to upload image to hsql database from extjs client side in json object

Tags: json, extjs, request, submit, image-uploading

I have image upload field like

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',  
    fieldLabel: 'Image',  
    labelSeparator: '',  
    name: 'newPic',  
    id:'newPic',  
    anchor:'100%',  
    inputType: 'file',  
    allowBlank: false  
}
```

When i submitting form, Im encoding all form data in a json object.All textfields data are coming in json object but not image is passing to server side . How to pass image so as to save it in server side

```
var form=Ext.getCmp('empPersonal');
var formdata=Ext.JSON.encode(form.getValues());
alert(""+formdata);
if(Ext.getCmp('empPersonal').getForm().isValid()) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({ 
    url:'ws/employees/create/'+formdata,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Ext.form.field.File` and not just `textfield`. This control will let user  browse for a file on local machine and this file will be included in the POST message sent to the server:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File